# Error adding Firebase users Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

By following the information on [this link](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/password.html), I am currently working on trying to create a user using Firebase, as shown in the code below. However, it appears no user is created when the app is run. Any input is greatly appreciated. The Firebase URL was taken from my test database.

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://test-96df2.firebaseio.com")
    ref.createUser("bobtony@example.com", password: "correcthorsebatterystaple",
                   withValueCompletionBlock: { error, result in
                    if error != nil {
                        // There was an error creating the account
                        print("error creating account")
                    } else {
                        let uid = result["uid"] as? String
                        print("Successfully created user account with uid: \(uid)")
                    }
    })
```

**Edit**:

The propagated error is:

> Error Code: AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED) Projects created at
>   console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication
>   SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

However, as shown below, the email/password authentication is enabled in the Firebase console.
[image]

Comment: debug it and take a look at the `error` object. it should have more details regarding the error.

Comment: what `firebase` version are you using?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which version of firebase I am using, but I believe the most recent one.

Comment: Your code appears to be Firebase 2.x but the console is the new one associated with Firebase 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already authorized the email registration as I can see in your screenshot. So the problem doesnt realies on `AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED`.

From your error message and the snippet code I can see that you have created a new project but you are trying to use the legacy firebase  SDK and so you will have compatibility issues. Also, you are looking into the old firebase documentation.

First of all you will need to make sure you have configured your project as documented in [new firebase start guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

After, you can take a look at the [documentation for creating a new user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account) with the new sdk. You can find the 3.x create user call bellow.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: password) { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```